# Converting decorators to their implementation code

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm learning about decorators and found this useful thread that really helped me a lot. 
[How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Based on what I understand, decorators are just syntactic sugar.  However I'm having trouble converting from the syntactic sugar code to non-syntactic sugar code.

```
# Decorators
def addBold(func):
    def wrapper(*arg1):
        print("Bold Added")
        return '<b>' + func(*arg1) + '</b>'
    return wrapper

def addItalic(func):
    def wrapper(*arg1):
        print("Italic Added")
        return '<i>' + func(*arg1) + '</i>'
    return wrapper
```

This code works:

```
@addBold
def getHTMLCode(passedText):
    return passedText

newVar = getHTMLCode('Hello')
print(newVar)
# outputs: Bold Added <b>Hello</b>
```

I tried converting to non-syntactic sugar code, but this not work (`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`):

```
def getHTMLCode(passedText):
    return passedText

newVar = addBold(getHTMLCode('Hello'))  # returns wrapper
newVar()
```

What does the working code (second block) look like w/o the decorator syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function you want wrapped to the decorator function and then call the returned wrapper with the arguments:

```
wrapped_getHTMLCode = addBold(getHTMLCode)
wrapped_getHTMLCode('Hello')
```

Notice how `wrapped_getHTMLCode` works like the decorated version of `getHTMLCode`. You call it with the string you want bolded, and it returns the string with HTML bold markup around it.